# Passing variable through multiple conditions without if?

Tags: python-3.x, function, conditional-statements, iterable, multiple-conditions

What I'm trying to do is to pass a variable through a function that has a list of multiple lambda condition functions.

This function should behave by either returning 1 if all conditions are met or stopping the "iteration" and returning which conditions was not met.

Something like this:

```
def is_conditions_met(y):

    conditions = (lambda x: 1 if isinstance(x, int) else return "Wrong type",
                  lambda x: 1 if x % 2 == 0 else return "Not even",
                  lambda x: 1 if x >= 40 else return "Less than 40")

    return all(conditions, y)

    >>> is_condition_met('foo')
    >>> ' Wrong type '

    >>> is_condition_met(14)
    >>> ' Less than 40 '

    >>> is_condition_met(42)
    >>> True
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `all()` is of no use here, since both possible return values from each lambda are truthy.  It might be better to reverse the logic - return False or None if the test passes, a string (non-empty and therefore truthy) to give details on any test failure.  That would make `any()` the relevant function, but it still wouldn't work because it doesn't give you the specific value that caused the function to end.  You will need to write an explicit loop over the lambdas, calling them and then returning if appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use IF, but use it more effective. In you variation all 3 functions will be executed no matter what.
I suggest to check conditions step by step.
For example, you don't need to execute 2 last functions if TYPE is not INT.
So my variation is:

```
def is_conditions_met(y):
    if not isinstance(y, int):
        return "Wrong type"

    # If type is INT we can check next condition and etc.
    if not y % 2 == 0:
        return "Not even"

    if not y >= 40:
        return "Less than 40"
    
    return True
```